# How can I concatenate and print only values from json object after calling json_decode in php?

Tags: php, json

This is a schema generator that displays the key:value pair

```
 "default": [
                {
                    "one": "u0001u0000u0000u0000",
                    "two": "u0002u0000u0000u0000",
                    "three": "u0003u0000u0000u0000"
                }
            ]
```

What I would like to print out is "default": `[{"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}]`

Similarly if it is an object for instance:

```
"default": [ "a":
                {
                    "one": "u0001u0000u0000u0000",
                    "two": "u0002u0000u0000u0000",
                    "three": "u0003u0000u0000u0000"
                }
            ]
```

concatenate only values and print like this:

```
["a": {"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}]
```

Sample Code Test:
// this method gets the value entered by user in json format. The user can put in a nested json format as well. The above examples that I mentioned works. 
it then calls for scanForNestedType method which scans whether the format contains any array, array>, map etc...
Once it scans for nested type, it internally calls $this->encodeValues($unit)which converts the values entered by user from integer to bytes.

Here is an example:

User enters array
[{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}]. After conversion, the result would be as follows:
[
 { 
   "one": u0001u0000u0000u0000,
   "two": u00002u0000u0000u0000,
   "three: u0003u0000u0000u0000
 }
]

Now I am getting the values correctly for each key. All I need is to print in this format:
[
  {
    u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000
  }
]

```
private function jsonDecode(array $value)
{
    $strValue = $value['value'];
    $jsonValue = json_decode($strValue);

    $this->scanForNestedType($jsonValue);
    return $jsonValue;
}

private function scanForNestedType(&$value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key => &$unit) {
        if (is_array($unit) || is_object($unit)) {
            $this->scanForNestedType($unit);
        } else {
            $value->$key = $this->encodeValues($unit);
        }
    }
}

private function encodeValues(int $value)
{
    $encodedValue = '';

    $bytesArray = unpack("C*", pack("V", $value));
    foreach ($bytesArray as $byte) {
        $encodedValue .= sprintf('u%04x', dechex($byte));
    }
    return $encodedValue;
}
```

If I get a working example then it would be great!

Comment: A simple [`join()`](http://php.net/join) should do, if decoded with `$assoc=TRUE`.

Comment: The second example is not valid JSON. Arrays don't have named keys. You can check it at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Apologies actually its in this format for the second example.                    
     "default": [{ "a":
                       {
                           "one": "u0001u0000u0000u0000",
                           "two": "u0002u0000u0000u0000",
                           "three": "u0003u0000u0000u0000"
                       }
                     }]

Comment: Your question is not clear, because it does not contain any code. In question title you say `after calling json_decode`, you mean you successfully decoded this (invalid) json string into PHP object, right?  Then what is the question? You don't know how to concatenate the values or you have a problem with iterating over the array, or something like these? If you clarify a little, we might be able to help, but right now your question only defines input and desired output, and leaves the whole coding part to us.

Comment: @SouravChatterjee please update the example in the question, so it's clear to everyone, rather than posting code in the comment section. Also please show what code you have tried so far. It should be easily possible (using google) to research how to loop an array, and how to combine some strings together using PHP. The logic isn't too complicated really, and the syntax is trivial. Please show that you've made some effort to solve this yourself before asking for the free time of other people. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson. I have updated my code. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` to convert json to an array. Then `implode` sub-array ['one'....] using foreach loop.

snippet

```
$json1 = '[{"one": "u0001u0000u0000u0000", "two": "u0002u0000u0000u0000", "three": "u0003u0000u0000u0000"}]';
$json2 = '[{ "a": { "one": "u0001u0000u0000u0000", "two": "u0002u0000u0000u0000", "three": "u0003u0000u0000u0000" } }]';
$arr1 = json_decode($json1,true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2,true);


foreach($arr1 as $data){
    $default1[] = implode($data);
}
$default1 = json_encode($default1, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

foreach($arr2 as $key => $child){
    foreach($child as $childKey => $data){
        $default2[$childKey] = implode($data);
    }
}
$default2 = json_encode($default2, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

print_r($default1);
print_r($default2);
```

Output

```
{"0":"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}
{"a":"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}
```

Live [Demo](https://3v4l.org/mpSMM)

You can now `json_decode` `$default1, $default2` to get php object/array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Smartpal. This is what I was looking for. However is there a way to remove the key ? for example show the result in the following format: [{"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}] and similar format for map [{"a": {"u0001u0000u0000u0000u0002u0000u0000u0000u0003u0000u0000u0000"}}]

Comment: Your expected result are not valid json. However, you can use preg_replace!